# TFS success build alert email if only the last buiild was a failure though TFS plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I currently have the TFS setup email alerts for failure and success builds. I think success build emails are just a noise and I want to get them only if the last build was a failure.

My idea was to cancel the TFS alert email for any success build, but enable it for success after failure builds.

I have successfully hooked up the code to find out if the last build failed and the current build succeeded using a TFS plugin.

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
    object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
{
    statusCode = 0;
    properties = null;
    statusMessage = string.Empty;

    var objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\tfsTests\builds.txt", true);
    objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "-----------------------------------------------");
    objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + notificationType.ToString());
    objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + notificationEventArgs.ToString());

    if ((notificationType == NotificationType.Notification) && (notificationEventArgs is BuildCompletionNotificationEvent))
    {
        var buildNotificationEventArgs = notificationEventArgs as BuildCompletionNotificationEvent;
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.ToString());
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.BuildControllerUri.ToString());
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.LastGoodBuildUri);
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.LastBuildUri);

        var locationService = requestContext.GetService<TeamFoundationLocationService>();
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
            new Uri(locationService.GetServerAccessMapping(requestContext).AccessPoint + "/" + requestContext.ServiceHost.Name));
        var buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.TeamProject, buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.Name);
        spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 2;
        spec.QueryOrder = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;

        var builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec);

        if (builds.Builds.Count() == 2)
        {
            if (builds.Builds[0].Status == BuildStatus.Succeeded && builds.Builds[1].Status != BuildStatus.Succeeded && builds.Builds[0].FinishTime > builds.Builds[1].FinishTime)
                objWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", "Send Email"));
        }
    }
    objWriter.Close();
    return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
}
```

Above code is working fine and I get the Send Email written in by text file.
I just don't know how to cancel/activate the TFS build email. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a built-in feature!

Answer (score 0):

You have subscribed to the Build Event. If you are using TFS 2013 or VSO you can open your team project in web access, then click the cog in the top right to go to the admin side. There should be an Alerts tab.

If you are still on a pre-2012 server in Visual Studio you can right-click on the Team Project in the Team Explorer and edit the Alerts.

Comment: The alerts explorer only gives you an option to send email when a build is successful or failed. I want the failure emails, but I want the success emails only when I fix a build after a failure. That is the reason I had to write this plugin. I have correctly figured out the successful build after a failed build. Now, I just need to stop the tfs build email which is sent out on every build and allow it only on the success after failure. I am using TFS 2012